# How can i copy a database from /data/data to an external folder, and viceversa?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an android application capable of storing Strings into a database.db. I'm not sure on how to be able to take the database from /data/data folder somewhere else (i need to do it because i want the user to be able to move the db file from /data/data even if he/she doesn't have root permission). I tried a lot of different ways, but nothing worked fine. Can you help me?

Comment: Define "somewhere else": Remote server, sdcard, ...?

Comment: What did you try? The database file is just a file. And can be copied. So what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I meant to ask how could I copy a dB file contained into /data/data folder to some other folder, and I found the way myself. I simply defined another constructor into my dB class, that I used to create a new dB file into the external storage path.